# Problem with clickable element - Selenium 4, Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I try to locate and click a link on the website.
But for some reason selenium cannot find the link and gives time out.
Without explicit wait gives element not found.

My code

```
url = "https://lineascan.build/address/0x578705c60609c9f02d8b7c1d83825e2f031e35aa#writeContract"
driver.get(url)

    # Wait for the "Connect to Web3" button to be clickable
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
connect_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Connect to Web3')]")))
connect_button.click()
```

Any clue why?

Comment: Exists, because can click it manually.. but selenium not see it.

Comment: When you ask a question on SO, you should always post any error message you get in your question... the full error message as text, properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few problems with your code.

1. The 'Connect to Web3' link is not a BUTTON, it's an A tag.
2. The 'Connect to Web3' link is in an IFRAME so you need to switch context into the containing IFRAME first before trying to find the link.

Fixing the link locator and adding a switch to the IFRAME, I came up with the working code below...

```
url = 'https://lineascan.build/address/0x578705c60609c9f02d8b7c1d83825e2f031e35aa#writeContract'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "writecontractiframe")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "connectStatus"))).click()
# when you are done working with elements inside this IFRAME, use the line below to switch back to the default context
driver.switch_to.default_content
```